# How to pass URL parameter to JavaScript function and create iframe element?

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe, parameters

I have a Beginner's question here...

i'm a mobile app, and desktop app developer, so I'm very bad in HTML & JavaScript and the entire web technology ... I have a very simple case but unable to solve it, so please help me out here

I have a very simple and straightforward html file, this file has an iFrame or JavaScript (i have both options) for a video chat API, I want to be able to pass a parameter with the URL, and this parameter should be part of the iFrame or the JavaScript call

**This is the original html code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Chat</title>
 </head>
 <body>

      
      <iframe
        src="https://tokbox.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=3ce25a03-f681-478d-9e4a-d7da94fd4945&room=DEFAULT_ROOM&iframe=true"
        width="900px"
        height="1400px"
        scrolling="auto"
        allow="microphone; camera"
      ></iframe>
    

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you have a JavaScript variable that you want to inject in the `src` attribute of your `<iframe>` element, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var iFrameElement = document.createElement('iframe');

// this will grab the url and split by # assuming you're passing the intended url after #
// if the intended url is already in the address bar, simply use 
// window.location.href
var url = window.location.href.split('#')[1]


// create the iframe element
iFrameElement.src =
  url;
iFrameElement.width = "900px"
iFrameElement.height = "1400px"
iFrameElement.scrolling="auto"
iFrameElement.allow="microphone; camera"


// create a new div to append the iframe to
var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
newDiv.appendChild(iFrameElement)


// append the div to body
document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the help ... i'm still getting an error

Comment: Hi man, thanks for the help ... still having an error on ht elast line of code app.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at app.js:24

Comment: can you share your html and js files? upload them on http://jsfiddle.net/ and click on save and paste the link in the comment and I'll take a look

Comment: seems that i was doing something wrong ... when i did a proper copy paste ... it worked ... thanks man .... i truly appreciate it